# Calculate SUBTOTAL of a SUMPRODUCT without a column for total

Tags: excel

I need to Calculate SUBTOTAL of a SUMPRODUCT without the column for total
I can't figure out this formula...
more precisely:

I need a formula that can Subtotal the Sumproduct(B2:B4,C2:C4)
or if I use a filter to SUBTOTAL only the visible cells in D1 (for example)

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can do it like this way
SUM(B2:B4)+SUM(C2:C4)

Comment: the sumproduct wil calculate the value for each product (the price x quantity)....
 what I need is in one cell to calculate the sumproduct and when I filter the preduct name to calculate SUBTOTAL only for visible cells

Comment: See my answer - that does what you describe

Answer (score 6):

You can use this approach

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B4,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(C2:C4,ROW(C2:C4)-MIN(ROW(C2:C4)),0,1)))`

that will give you the same result as before with everything visible but if you filter the second part will give you zero for the hidden rows and hence will effectively ignore them

Answer (score 1):

Just to take this a step further, you can also incorporate in a criteria, so that e.g. you can have a summary table working off the filtered data:- (e.g. you might want a total line for US, and another for UK, so you can incorporate a country check)

If you replace the "multiplication commas" for "multiplication asterisks (and I also put each block to be multiplied in brackets to keep it neat), and then add another multiplication block. Below I've added `(G6:G523=E2)*` , where `G` could be my country column, and `E2` is the Country I want to know the filtered summary for...

> =SUMPRODUCT((G6:G523=E2)*(E6:E523)*(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(E6:E523,ROW(E6:E523)-MIN(ROW(E6:E523)),0,1))))

I know, somebody is going to say "why don't you just filter by the country?"....well I might want a whole block of totals, and want to see the total for UK and the total for US beneath it.