# Calculate a Subtotal of a Sumproduct

Tags: excel

I believe I am asking the same questions as was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739663/calculate-subtotal-of-a-sumproduct-without-a-column-for-total/18740608#18740608?newreg=165e9bc2614e4914b81554a7210902fa), but am unable to comment and cannot make the accepted answer from @barry houdini work.

My situation is very similar, as I need a subtotal of a sumproduct, so that when I filter my results, I get an updated total representative of the displayed data.

More specifically, I want the sumproduct of qty and price, but if there is a purchase date, I want to filter to show only Blank cells in that column to find the outstanding purchasing total.

```
Quantity             Price              Purchase Date
1                    150                3/1/2017
2                    500                           
1                    50                 3/15/2017
1                    100
```

Is there an easy way to do this in one formula without needing extra columns for totals? Or should I come at it a different way?

Comment: will you always only want those without dates?  because you do not need to filter and use subtotal for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your data setup the formula would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(A2:A5,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(B2:B5,ROW(B2:B5)-MIN(ROW(B2:B5)),0,1)))
```

[image]

But if you always want the non date sumproduct then you do not need the subtotal or the filter.  Just use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$5="")*$A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5)
```

[image]